# Are most websites out there built on XHTML rather than HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

Recall the fact brought up by [this lesson](http://www.udemy.com/lectures/1-what-is-xhtml-and-css-70050) of the Become a Web Developer From Scratch course on Udemy. Would be great to hear some observations here, as I'm having trouble finding anything conclusive on Wikipedia, Google, or even here on Stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Number of questions tagged html: 89429. Number of questions tagged xhtml: 4001. Big clue there, I think.

Comment: @Alohci: Does that mean html is still more common despite xhtml is newer standard?

Comment: html5 is the newest standard. yes, xhtml is newer than html and still more popular than html5, but the web is moving to html5.

Comment: could you unmark my answer as best please, it's misleading and incorrect

Answer (score 2):

[Some statistics](http://blog.powermapper.com/blog/post/HTML-vs-XHTML-Version-Statistics.aspx) suggest that xhtml is more common nowadays, but I believe that most of the xhtml pages are served as html to browsers (meaning that they are not sent from server as application/xhtml+xml, application/xml, or text/xml, maybe because [support on some browsers](http://caniuse.com/xhtml) has not been so good).

HTML5 is now here and it is meant to avoid the problems of html/xhtml debate. Browsers already support the basics coming from earlier versions so I suggest you stick to that and do not look back.

Comment: I'm actually going through XHTML as a starting point before working on HTML5. I thought HTML5 is there not just to eliminate the confusion, but also add multimedia support for iOS devices?

Comment: @stanigator - HTML5 adds a good many things. But you are right in that it doesn't eliminate the confusion/debate since HTML5 contains both HTML and XHTML serializations within it.

Comment: As I see it, HTML5 point is to be descriptive instead of prescriptive (like html 4.x and xhtml 1.x were). It tries to document how things normally work so that there is a reference for users and implementors alike.

Comment: @Edu - I'd say that the specs for all HTML versions have been a mixture of describing what actually happens, and what the spec writers would like or expect to happen in the future. In that respect, HTML5 differs only in that things which aren't currently supported, and which the browser manufacturers don't give a commitment to support, don't make it into the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, HTML:XHTML is about 2:1 according to the [MAMA](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama-the-url-set/)'s [study](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama-key-findings/#structsize) carried out in 2008 by examining 3,509,180 URLs in 3,011,668 domains.

I am not sure how exactly things have been changed in less than 4 years, but I would be highly suspicious of any claim that XHTML is more popular than HTML unless backed with specific data source.

[Source](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama-key-findings/#structsize)

[MAMA](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama-the-url-set/)

Comment: @CoryDanielson Why were they never actually XHTML? Just curious.

Comment: clarifications: If you adhere to the rules of the XHTML Transitional DTD while writing your markup, you are writing a blend of HTML/XML known as XHTML or (X)HTML. It's more-or-less HTML code with an XML backbone... (follows XML rules), but there is a distinction between HTML, XHTML and XML. They are all different, but **very** similar. The XHTML rules are so heavily adopted that they have become best practices for people who write HTML. Simply put, modern HTML is XHTML; the markup is XHTML compliant, but not sent from the webserver specifically as XHTML because of inconsistencies doing that.

Comment: @CoryDanielson Ah since you deleted your comment, I no longer remember what I was asking in the comment above ;)